# Crond stopped sending e-mails for no apparent reason

Tags: linux, email, postfix, cron, ruby-on-rails

I have a cron job that I want to run just once a day (executes a rake task), but while I'm testing it I have it set to run every 5 minutes. It was running perfectly fine this morning and sending me e-mails with the output but it has inexplicably stopped sending me mail.

When I checkout `/var/log/syslog` I can see that the cron job is still running, but the line that normally shows an email being sent has stopped appearing.

When I run `service postfix status` I get `postfix is running.`

I haven't changed the cron job itself. I still have this:

```
MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
*/5 * * * * cd /u/apps/myapp/current && /usr/local/bin/rake my_task RAILS_ENV=staging
```

No idea what's going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your mail logs ?

Comment: If there is no output from the job, cron doesn't send email.

Comment: According to `/var/log/mail.log` the last e-mail was sent at 10:00 AM and then it just stops

Comment: That was it, @FredtheMagicWonderDog. I had made a change to the rake task that was producing no output. Do you want to add that as the answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I may have missed it, but I looked through the linked question and I do not see the answer that is explicitly relevant to this question ("If there is no output from the job, cron doesn't send email") stated anywhere

Comment: It was implied by  `... By default cron will mail any output from the command to the user`, I have fixed it to explicitly state that there needs to be output for mail to be generated.